# Processing: Using rollover with text from table

Tags: processing, rollover, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file that was created from a plain text file. In column A there is a list of unique words and in column B it lists their frequency within that text.

I am using Processing and loadTable to draw a list of the words. I would like to use rollover so that when the mouse hovers over them, an ellipse appears that has a size relative to the integer associated with that word's frequency.

I am having a hard time finding a good example of the syntax for using rollover() while in a loop that includes data from a CSV file.

Any help is appreciated!

```
void setup() {
  table = loadTable("tabletest.csv", "header");
  size(600,1000);
}  

void draw() {
  background(252, 245, 224);
  for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    TableRow row = table.getRow(i);

    String w = row.getString("Word");
    int f = row.getInt("Frequency");
    textSize(10);
    text(w, width/2, 15*i);
    fill(8, 114, 105);
    textAlign(CENTER);

    }
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Rollover example](https://processing.org/examples/rollover.html). Perhaps you can adapt that to a box around the text

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in `rollover()` function that I know of. You're going to have to write this functionality yourself.

You can check whether the cursor is inside a given rectangle. See [this guide](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection#rectangle-point-collision) for more info, but basically you check whether `mouseX` is between the left and right and whether `mouseY` is between the top and bottom of the rectangle.

If so, then you know the mouse is inside that table cell and you can take the appropriate action. I recommend [breaking your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and taking those steps on one at a time. For example, start over with a basic sketch that shows a single rectangle that changes color when the mouse is inside it. Get that working perfectly before trying to make it work with multiple rectangles.

Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific technical question. Good luck.